# How can I see the full error or warning in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, xcode4

No matter how large I make the window, this is all I can see of warnings:

[image]

How can I see the full text of the warning at the place it appears?

I *could* hover the mouse over the warning as it appears in the left pane and, after waiting long enough, a tooltip appears with the full text, but I find this very awkward... Is this the only way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Issue Navigator is a compact representation. If you really want *all* the details, you can view the build transcript:

- cmd+7
- click on the top-most "Build $APP" section.
- locate the warning or error
- click the buttons on the right to see the full details of the step you are interested in

Double clicking on a message will then reveal the source location in the editor.

Answer (score 38):

**#### Here's a very handy trick: ####**

**1)** Look in the *issue navigator*

[image]

**2)** Go to: xCode preferences > General > "Issue Navigator Detail" > now boost the dropdown to **10 lines**.

Now you can see the whole message in the issue navigator!

[image]

Answer (score 8):

The easiest way to do it is right clicking the message in the "Issue Navigator" and choosing "Reveal in Log".

Comment: this is particularly helpful when you have a linker error and selecting it in the issue window doesn't reveal an more details about the situation causing the link error.  selecting reveal in log will show the full details in this situation. very helpful!

Comment: I have a linker error, but by right click on the error and select 'reveal in log' doesn't show any more detail.

Comment: That only works about 50% of the time. Or less... sigh.

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode 9.2 (at least), you can single click on the error / warning **icon** in the tooltip and it will expand.

Answer (score 1):

2023 answer: To view the specific build error IE "Command XYZ failed with a nonzero exit code"

1. Go to Xcode > View > Navigators > Reports
2. On the Reports screen expand the error message.

Shortcut CMD+9

Comment: Stating the year isn't very useful. State what version of Xcode you are referring to.

Answer (score 0):

you can find, the warning/error list in the Warning tab section on the left

Answer (score 0):

You can similarly hover over the warning itself. Even "unused variable" can be squished small enough so it can't fit (if you downsize the editor enough). Hover over the warning in place is the closest you'll come.

Answer (score -1):

I'm sure if you expand the left hand pane, it shows the full error. Ensure you are in the Warnings/Errors tab.

As far as I'm aware, this is the only way to do it.

Comment: Yes, I sometimes do that, but that's even more awkward... Especially if the text is long enough that it doesn't fit in one line on the screen.